# Color Scheme In ggplot2 facet_wrap

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, data-science

I am making a multiple scatterplot to show interaction. I used the melt function from the reshape2 package to make my data look like this:

```
head(wage)
  money educ exper tenure nonwhite female    married numdep smsa Region Industry
1  3.10   11     2      0    White Female Notmarried      2    1   west    other
2  3.24   12    22      2    White Female    Married      3    1   west services
3  3.00   11     2      0    White   Male Notmarried      2    0   west    trade
4  6.00    8    44     28    White   Male    Married      0    1   west  clerocc
5  5.30   12     7      2    White   Male    Married      1    0   west    other
6  8.75   16     9      8    White   Male    Married      0    1   west profserv


test1 = wage %>% select(money, educ, female, nonwhite, married, smsa, Region, Industry)
test1a = melt(test1, id.vars= c('money', 'educ'))

head(test1a)

      money educ variable  value
    1  3.10   11   female Female
    2  3.24   12   female Female
    3  3.00   11   female   Male
    4  6.00    8   female   Male
    5  5.30   12   female   Male
    6  8.75   16   female   Male

tail(test1a)
         money educ variable    value
    3151  5.65   12 Industry construc
    3152 15.00   16 Industry profserv
    3153  2.27   10 Industry    trade
    3154  4.67   15 Industry construc
    3155 11.56   16 Industry   nondur
    3156  3.50   14 Industry profserv
```

The ggplot function I am using is:

```
ggplot(test1a, aes(educ,money, col = value )) + geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~ variable) + geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = FALSE) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

Which is giving me the following plot:
[image: Plot]

Which is exactly what I'm looking for, except I want all 6 plots to have the same color scheme. In other words, I want all 6 plots to have the same exact green/yellow plot as they have in the top left.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you've got more than one type of measurement in the `variable` and `value` columns. For example, you at least have both gender and industry in those columns. If you show us a sample of your data before melting (paste into your question the output of `dput(data_sample)`) and tell use what you intend `variable` and `value` to actually represent, we can help you shape your data properly.

Comment: Basically I just don't like the color scheme as it is hard to see. Another thing I was thinking of doing is making each point black but each regression line a different color? Just something to make these interactions easier to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generated some data to illustrate this answer

```
test1a <- data.frame(money = rnorm(10), educ = rnorm(10), 
                     variable = c("female","female","female","female","female","Industry","Industry","Industry","Industry","Industry"),
                     value = c("Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "construc", "construc", "trade", "trade", "trade"))

        money         educ variable    value
1   0.6509500  0.822198786   female   Female
2  -0.7038793  0.257554982   female   Female
3  -0.9110664 -1.048976078   female     Male
4   0.1313963 -1.398813412   female     Male
5  -0.6050824  0.818251963   female   Female
6   1.2937046 -0.289675281 Industry construc
7   1.1670726 -0.004767622 Industry construc
8   0.3489473 -0.633061650 Industry    trade
9  -0.1536924 -0.567433569 Industry    trade
10  1.3932668 -0.010446676 Industry    trade
```

Libraries used

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
```

First of all get a table of variable-values being used

```
uniqueVarVal <- unique(test1a[,3:4])

  variable    value
1   female   Female
3   female     Male
6 Industry construc
8 Industry    trade
```

The aim is to get a manual color scale for the female variable and use the **same** scheme for the Industry variable.

Colors to be used. I've only specified 2, **you will need more colours**, as some of your variables have more than 2 values.

```
colors <- c("red", "green")
```

Add the color to be used to our table of variable-values

```
colValues <- uniqueVarVal %>%
    group_by(variable) %>%
    mutate(color = colors[row_number()]) %>%
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  variable    value color
    <fctr>   <fctr> <chr>
1   female   Female   red
2   female     Male green
3 Industry construc   red
4 Industry    trade green
```

Next we need to set the levels of the value variable, otherwise ggplot arranges them alphabetically.

```
test1a$value <- factor(test1a$value, levels = colValues$value)
```

Finally specify a manual color scale using the repeated pattern, red-green.

```
ggplot(test1a, aes(educ,money, col = value )) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.3) +
    geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = FALSE)  +
    scale_color_manual(values = colValues$color) +
    facet_wrap(~ variable)
```

I have left the legend showing, so you can see what is happening.

Given the density of your points, I'd recommend using alpha to set transparency.
[image]

Comment: You're welcome. If this works for you, would you mark the answer as accepted and give it your upvote. Thanks